# In asymptotic notation, given g(n), is the union of O(g(n)) and Ω(g(n)) the universal set U of all functions?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

It seems yes.  Any intuitive or serious proof is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

No.

I think your question is equivalent to this: given functions f and g, is it always true that either f is O(g) or g is O(f)?  This is answered in the SE Computer Science question [Are the functions always asymptotically comparable?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1780/are-the-functions-always-asymptotically-comparable).  If f and g are not comparable via big-O, then f is not in O(g), and f is not in big-Omega(g) either.

For an example, take the top answer to the SE question above: define f(n) = n, and define g(n) = 1 (if n is odd), n^2 (if n is even).  No matter how far out you go, sometimes f is much bigger than g, and sometimes g is much bigger than f.  So f is neither in O(g) nor in big-Omega(g).

Comment: I think you are right, that the answer is "No", but I have no idea if it's equivalent to that other question. How about just giving a simple example or more precisely, a counterexample? Let g(n) = n and f(n) = 1 for odd n and n*n for even n.  f(n) doesn’t belong to O(g(n)) and doesn’t belong to big-Omega(g(n)) and it’s definitely a function :)

Comment: Sure, I'll pull that example into this answer.